# Is it true that "volatile" in a userspace program tends to indicate a bug?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When I googling about "volatile" and its user space usage, I found mails between Theodore Tso and Linus Torvalds. According to these great masters, use of "volatile" in userspace probably be a bug??[Check discussion here](https://yarchive.net/comp/volatile.html)

Although they have some explanations, but I really couldn't understand. Could anyone use some simple language explain why they said so? We are not suppose to use volatile in user space??

Comment: Not necessarily, but it *is* used a lot by people who don't know what it means. There's a common misconception that it has something to do with threads, for example.

Comment: One place where it's often needed is in [signal handlers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal). Also with [setjmp/longjmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp).

Comment: This is a very broad question. Volatile can be used correctly, but it is more often misused. If you are in doubt about using volatile in a specific piece of code, show that piece of code.

Comment: @Shawn Unless the compiler can guarantee that it understands that callback functions can be called by someone else than the program itself, all variables shared with a callback function need to be `volatile`. Now as it happens, most of the mainstream PC compilers do not assume that callback functions aren't called, but it wasn't always so. That's where the need of `volatile` in multi-threading originates from, since threads use callbacks. It is not a misconception, it is a historical reason. That `volatile` could somehow be used to fix race conditions is however a misconception.

Comment: @Shawn, I/O in userspace (after *ioprot()* IIRC its name) might require this, if the address is kept in the variable.

Comment: @Lundin Hi, can you kindly provide some explanation or links of "all variables shared with a callback function need to be volatile" part? I still feel confuse this part..

Comment: @MichaelPeng Basically, if a compiler can tell that a function will not get called, it can optimize away that function. This in turn means that it can at the same time deduct that any variable shared with that function will not get updated, it can be optimized away. Thus if I have this in the main program: `bool foo = false; ... while(foo){ do_stuff(); }` where `foo` in only written to by a function that is never called, the compiler can optimize away the whole loop. -->

Comment: Now, if the function is a callback, the compiler needs to realize that it can be called by the OS or hardware, rather than from the program. If the compiler doesn't realize that, variables shared with the callback function simply must be volatile so that the compiler can't make assumptions about them, or otherwise the optimizer will destroy the whole code. PC compilers are nowadays aware, but it wasn't always so. In embedded systems, this is still a problem. And the bugs created by missing volatile are _very_ subtle.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin .Very clear and helpful. Now I understand :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`volatile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile) tells the compiler that every read and write has an observable side effect; thus, the compiler can't make any assumptions about two reads or two writes in a row having the same effect.

For instance, normally, the following code:

```
int a = *x;
int b = *x;
if (a == b)
    printf("Hi!\n");
```

Could be optimized into:

```
printf("Hi!\n");
```

What `volatile` does is tell the compiler that those values might be coming from somewhere outside of the program's control, so it has to actually read those values and perform the comparison.

A lot of people have made the mistake of thinking that they could use `volatile` to build lock-free data structures, which would allow multiple threads to share values, and they could observe the effects of those values in other threads.

However, `volatile` says nothing about how different threads interact, and could be applied to values that could be cached with different values on different cores, or could be applied to values that can't be atomically written in a single operation, and so if you try to write multi-threaded or multi-core code using `volatile`, you can run into a lot of problems.

Instead, you need to either use locks or some other standard concurrency mechanism to communicate between threads, or use [memory barriers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence), or use C11/C++11 [atomic types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic) and [atomic operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic). Locks ensure that an entire region of code has exclusive access to a variable, which can work if you have a value that is too large, too small, or not aligned to be atomically written in a single operation, while memory barriers and the atomic types and operations provide guarantees about how they work with the CPU to ensure that caches are synchronized or reads and writes happen in particular orders.

Basically, `volatile` winds up mostly being useful when you're interfacing with a single hardware register, which can vary outside the programs control but may not require any special atomic operations to access. Or it can be used in [signal handlers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal), where because a thread could be interrupted, and the handler run, and then control returned within the same thread, you need to use a `volatile` value if you want to communicate a flag to the interrupted code.

But if you're doing any kind of sychronization between threads, you should be using locks or some other concurrency primitives provided by a standard library, or really know what you're doing with regards to memory ordering and use memory barriers or atomic operations.

Comment: Nice! Thanks coach:) One more question, you mentioned "...could be applied to values that could be cached with different values on different cores, or could be applied to values that can't be atomically written in a single operation..", so volatile actually not guaranteed to read directly on RAM(can be cached)? It only effect on compile time to discard optimization?

Comment: not exactly to discsrd optimisations. it only guarantees that (simplifying) it will be read before every use and saved every time it changes.

Comment: @MichaelPeng Pretty much; `volatile` only guarantees that the compiler will perform reads and writes in each place that there is a read or write in your code, but it doesn't affect how those reads or writes are done, so it doesn't guarantee atomic access, it doesn't guarantee that the reads and writes will reach main memory in CPUs with caches, and it doesn't guarantee anything about the order of reads and writes as seen by other CPUs. It doesn't "discard optimizations," but it does guarantee that optimizations won't affect the order and number of reads and writes to location referenced.